# Move row from current table to History table and update the current table

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I had a table with a computed column and unique column now what i need to do his On click event the data in current table should be moved to history table and update the current table with latest computed number

For Example Computed column Number is VR000005 and unique column Number is AP25GV2121 , at click event if data is matching with unique column and if there are any changes in front end the first given data need to move to history table and in current table with same unique column number the data need to update with different computed column number

```sql
declare    @ves    int,    @MaxRCNo    int,    @MaxRCNo1    int
if    exists(select   *   from   HistoryTable where   UniqueNumber = 
     'AP25GV2121 ' )

set   @ves =  (select  MAX(VersionNo)  from  HistoryTable  where  UniqueNumber = 'AP25GV2121 ')
set  @MaxRCNo  =  (select  MAX(RegNo)  from  CurrentTable)
set  @ves =  @ves+1 
set  @MaxRCNo =  @MaxRCNo+1

update  HistoryTable  set  VersionNo = @ves where VersionNo=0  and  UniqueNumber = 'AP25GV2121 '

insert  into  HistoryTable  
Select  *  from  CurrentTable  where  UniqueNumber =  'AP25GV2121 '

Update  CurrentTable  set Type = 'TW' , Category ='PER' , Currency = 'IND' , Duration = 2, Fee = 500, bookFee = 700,
    Fine = 200, Amount = 1400  where  UniqueNumber = 'AP25GV2121 '
```

Should i use triggers or it is possible with stored procedure only can anyone help me out?

Comment: I guess both is possible, the question is if you need to have this as a transaction. By 2019 all SQL DBMSs  should rollback actions in- and outside of a trigger but you should double check for your case. In an SP you normally act in a single transition anyway.

Comment: I tried by using the SP only everything is working fine but the problem is that in History table VersionNo and RegNo is showing Null instead of representing a value

Comment: Also while performing operations from front-end it is showing error near the commuted column as Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.